# How do I upload files in Drupal 7 without them being renamed?

Tags: drupal-7

I would like to upload files on Drupal 7 and keep the name the same.

Currently when I upload a file again, the name is appended with and underscore and number.

e.g.

filename_0.pdf

Q: How do I avoid this file renaming?

Answer (score 0):

This module looks like it does exactly what you want:
https://www.drupal.org/project/upload_replace

Comment: Thanks, I will check that one out. The attachment links module also looks promising - it doesn't change the renaming but it creates a permalink you can use instead of the actual name, and manages versions of it.